# How to run project on GitLab with different Java version and Maven version?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently, in .gitlab.xml I have added maven version. mvn -version
and I get following

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.0 (ef0b1a6)
  on aldo-esb-app01 (ed33de66)
Using Shell executor...
Running on aldo-esb-app01...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 6b74e38 remove .settings,project and change parent
From https://gitlab.chintegrator.cosng.net/chintegrator/filemover/filemover-generic
   6b74e38..aef376b  feature/java11change -> origin/feature/java11change
Checking out aef376b1 as feature/java11change...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: /shared/gitlab-runner/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
Job succeeded
```

Now, I'm migrating from Java 8 to 11.

So, I need to keep both Java 8 and Java 11 (for master project), as well as Maven 3.6 and 3.8 (for 11) (for feature branch only).

How can I configure both together so that Java 8 build runs with Java 8 and Java 11 projects build with Java 11 and Maven 3.8?

In Maven Parent, We have already started using Maven 3.8 with `<release>11`, but it is not getting build.

Comment: Why do you need to use different Maven versions? (use Maven 3.8.4)...furthermore using different JDKs is not needed as well. you can build with JDK11 and produce code for JRE 8... (--release option!)...

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be using the shell executor, you can [use sdkman](https://sdkman.io/usage) to both download/install/use specific versions of Java, Maven, or numerous other candidate target tools (ant, gradle, etc).

For docker-based executors (like on gitlab.com shared runners), you can control this with the `image:` tag by specifying an image containing the version of maven/java you need.

For example, to use maven 3.8.5 on Java 11:

```yaml
job:
  image: maven:3.8.5-openjdk-11-slim
  script:
    - java -version
    - mvn -version
```